# How to make filebeat exclude certain docker container logs?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, filebeat

How to make filebeat exclude certain docker container logs?

Below is our filebeat.yml configuration file.

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  paths:
   - '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'
  multiline:
    pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
    negate: true
    match: after
  exclude_files:
   - filebeat-.*\.log
  processors:
  - add_docker_metadata: ~

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
  username: "elastic"
  password: "lZgjAPYnA3PJhz0bKZDY2gkJ"
```

Even after adding  `exclude_files` filebeat field/parameter filebeat is not excluding our desired docker container logs which in this case filebeat docker container logs which are deployed as agent in our docker installed VMs to capture desired applicaton/docker conatiner logs.

So, what filebeat parameters need to be added to exclude filebeat agent docker container logs from being shipped to our elasticsearch database?

Comment: why? filter them in elastic.

Comment: Do you mean, we can exclude logs coming from filebeat containers in the elastic-search configuration or filter filebeat logs in Kibana UI?

Comment: You can filter the results in kibana with the field `log.origin.filename` or something along those lines. BUT the data is still going to be ingested and take disk space.

Which version of filebeat do you use ?

Comment: ```filebeat:7.9.1``` version